# Do these two statements in The Rails 5 Way contradict each other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, rails-activerecord

I'm reading "The Rails 5 Way" now, and I've reached the section covering `includes` and `joins`.  Up until now my understanding has been that `includes` is best-suited for eager-loading DB data into memory in order to avoid N+1 queries, while `joins` is more appropriate for doing simple filtering of a query result set based on associated tables, without actually accessing the attributes on those associated table rows:

1

> **includes(*associations)** 
>   Active Record has the capability to eliminate
>   “N+1” queries by letting you specify what associations to eager load
>   using the `includes` method or option in your finders. Active Record
>   will load those relationships with the minimum number of queries
>   possible.

2

> **joins(expression)** `joins` works similarly to includes using an INNER
>   JOIN in the resulting SQL query. One of the key bits of knowledge to
>   understand about inner joins is they return only the set of records
>   that match the tables being joined. If a row on either side of the
>   join is missing its corresponding row on the other side, neither will
>   be returned in the result set.

However, on page 202 I see the following:

3

> By far the most common usage of the `joins` method is to eager-fetch
>   data for associated objects in a single SELECT statement in order to
>   prevent so-called N+1 queries.

The usage described in quote #3 seems to be a closer fit with quote #1 than quote #2, i.e. it talks about the goal of reducing N+1 queries by eager-loading the data (which I know `includes` does by calling either `eager_load` or `preload` under the hood).  To be honest, quote #3 doesn't appear to match #1 at all.

My question is- how can we reconcile these 3 quotes with each other?  Or are they already in sync with each other and I'm simply missing something?

Comment: Third quote is simply incorrect. Joins does not load associated records.

Comment: Eager vs lazy is orthogonal to includes vs join. Includes implicitly joins. If you *do* N+1 instead of avoiding it then obviously specify N query is "eager" in the informal sense that you evaluate it before the +1 query. The use of "eager" in quote 3 is wrong--they mean something like, simultaneously specify the N & (via the join) the +1. PS Please give a link.

Comment: i think we're confusing with eager-load vs eager-fetch in third quote. i'm sure the writer would have used eager-load as that term is more common; There has to be a reason why eager-fetch is used. Using joins, yes I do see how data for associated objects can be eager fetched. The sentence actually does say "how data for associated objects"; Building the associated objects through joins was probably out of scope for this quote.

Comment: Could be that the author is talking about selecting from the joined table without loading the association. `Foo.select(“foos.*, bars.baz AS baz”).joins(:bar)`. This can be used with aggregates like count or average. But this is not actually that common.

Comment: @philipxy- can you clarify what kind of link you mean?  The 3 quotes are from a book, not from a page I can link to.  I could link to the book's page on Amazon, if that will help, but I did mention the book's title already so I'm not sure how much added benefit that would be.